# Error using TSSLSocket.obj for Apache Thrift in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, openssl, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors, thrift

I'm trying to use Apache Thrift in a Visual Studio c++ Project (v141 Visual Studio Community 2017). I have followed the instructions from this site http://mohamednadjibmami.com/apache-thrift-for-c-on-visual-studio-2015/ to build the libraries. Because I want to develop for x64 I have build the Project Library for x64 with x64 boost libraries.
Now I have tried everything to get it to run, but I always run into linker errors even though the libraries are present and, I think, properly linked.

Is there maybe something I need to change when I'm building the library, or is it maybe not even possible to build it for 64bit because of OpenSSL 32 which seems to be somewhat relevant to the problem. (Yes I have linked OpenSSL headers and libraries to the thrift Project)

Maybe someone has encountered a similar problem and can help me, or has any idea what might the problem here. Thanks in advance.

The following picture shows the Error messages I receive from only the TSSLSocket:
[image]

**Edit:** I dont think its a duplicate to the mentioned topic, because it is a specific Problem and not a general Linker Problem. Or Please explain to me how this [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) is applicable in my case.

Comment: You say it's not a duplicate but I'm of the opinion that it takes more than 3 minutes to read the linked post.

Comment: You are right, but I have read a lot about this the last hours. "The order in which interdependent linked libraries are specified is wrong." maybe the problem here. But i tried to recompile it many times in different ways and specify the libboost librarys specificly as described in the from me above. Nothing worked or changed anything,